# Use WebService input as query parameter in reader module in Azure ML?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to use the parameters incoming from the webservice ( named 'Query' in my case ), in the SQL in the reader module.

I think it's possible, but I cannot find anywhere how to template these properties in the SQL query so that it becomes dynamic.

[image: dynamic query]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you'd have to implement the logic for inserting the query key in the client application that calls the web service. Support for parameterized SQL queries is in our feature backlog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Here is the blog demonstrating "how-to" for web service parameters - http://blogs.technet.com/b/machinelearning/archive/2014/11/25/azureml-web-service-parameters.aspx

Comment: AFAIK - this post shows how to supply the full query as a parameter. But I would like to add a query *parameter* only from the incoming web service request - not the full query. This turned out not to be possible.